# Ошибка в кодировке при добавлении в базу на php

Tags: php, mysql

Пример кракозябр:

> Ð°Ð¼Ð²Ð°Ð¿Ð²Ð°

Подключаюсь так:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Ниже код, который добавляет запись в бд. У бд кодировка `utf8_general_ci`, скрипта `utf8`, запускал с разных серверов, итог один. Кодировка ajax запроса, который записывает данные в переменные тоже `utf8`, кодировка переменных, которыми оперирует php тоже `utf8`. (проверял через функцию). Вывожу переменные в консоль браузера через ajax из php и они не отображаются кракозябрами! Я уже не знаю, что делать.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO users_1 (
user_id, user_status, user_email, user_pass, user_name, user_surname, user_avatar)
VALUES (NULL, "2", ?, ?, ?, ?, "/front/img/users/user.png");');

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $this->email, $this->pass, $this->name, $this->surname);

/* выполнение подготовленного выражения  */
if (!$stmt->execute())
echo "Кодировка имени " . mb_detect_encoding($this->name);

/* Закрытие соединения и выражения*/
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Проверьте как браузер распознаёт кодировку выдачи. Может это его глюк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сразу после успешного подключения выполнить следующий код:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Либо можно ещё попробовать выполнить следующий запрос:

```
SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8',
character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8',
character_set_server = 'utf8'
```

Получить текущую кодировку подключения можно следующим кодом:

```
$mysqli->character_set_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал этот пример:

*Необходимо отредактировать файл /etc/mysql/my.cnf*

*В секцию [mysqld] добавьте следующие строки:*

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server = utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Я отредактировал другой файл конфигурации: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf, т.к. указанный в мануале пуст. Не стал заморачиваться с копированием.

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/mysql